# Which expression is correct for using the sign $:=$ in the given problem?

Tags: notation, definition, scientific-notation

Imagine that I have this limit
$$ \lim_{x\to a}   f(x)=\frac{b^2-c^3}{8b^2-9c^2+a} ,$$
and I want to denote its RHS by another notation, say, $g$. Then, which notation is correct

$$ \lim_{x\to a}   f(x)=\frac{b^2-c^3}{8b^2-9c^2+a}:=g ,$$
or
$$ \lim_{x\to a}   f(x)=g:=\frac{b^2-c^3}{8b^2-9c^2+a} ,$$

Comment: Both are fine, in my opinion. I’d personally do it the other way round though: $$g:=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\cdots$$

Comment: But really, which one I’d prefer depends on context. They’re all ok

Comment: either $g:=...$ or $...=:g$, but not $...:=g$

Comment: I agree with @Surb, if you are defining $g$, it has to be $g:=$ or $=:g$.

Comment: @Surb Thanks. So, is this correct $ \lim_{x\to a}   f(x)=\frac{b^2-c^3}{8b^2-9c^2+a}=:g $?

Comment: yes it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

None of them are correct. I would write instead:

Setting $$g = \frac{b^2-c^3}{8b^2-9c^2+a},$$ one has $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = g.$$